# How to add third party dependency in osgi Liferay DXP

Tags: oracle, jdbc, gradle, liferay, osgi

I am working with Liferay DXP and I have created a service-builder module. In this module, I have to use the "oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" class  because I have developed a FinderImpl in order to add a method. This method calls a procedure which is in a database, this database is not the database of Liferay, I am using other databade for the procedure.

I have the JDBC driver (ojdbc7.jar) in lib/ext.

The build.gradle file is:

```
repositories {
   mavenLocal()
   mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
   compileOnly group: "biz.aQute.bnd", name: "biz.aQute.bndlib", version: "3.1.0"
   compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.osgi.util", version: "3.0.0"
   compileOnly group: "com.liferay", name: "com.liferay.portal.spring.extender", version: "2.0.0"
   compileOnly group: "com.liferay.portal", name: "com.liferay.portal.kernel", version: "2.6.0"
   compileOnly project(":modules:test-manager:test-manager-api")
   compileOnly group: "com.oracle", name: "ojdbc7", version: "12.1.0"
}

buildService {
   apiDir = "../test--manager-api/src/main/java"
   osgiModule = true
   propsUtil = "com.test.manager.service.util.ServiceProps"
}

group = "com.test.manager"
```

The bnd.bnd file is:

```
Bundle-Name: test-manager-service 
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.test.manager.service 
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0 
Liferay-Require-SchemaVersion: 1.0.0 
Liferay-Service: true
```

When I deploy the module I get this error:

```
Error while starting bundle: file:/C:/projects/test/modules/test-manager-service/test-manager-service-service/build/libs/com.test.manager.service-1.0.0.jar
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Could not resolve module: com.test.manager.service [536]_  Unresolved requirement: Import-Package: oracle.jdbc.driver_ [Sanitized]
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:429)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.start(EquinoxBundle.java:402)
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundle(DirectoryWatcher.java:1253)
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.startBundles(DirectoryWatcher.java:1225)
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.doProcess(DirectoryWatcher.java:512)
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.process(DirectoryWatcher.java:361)
        at org.apache.felix.fileinstall.internal.DirectoryWatcher.run(DirectoryWatcher.java:312)
```

Someone knows which is the problem? and how should I add the ojdbc7.jar in my module to use the oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver class?

Thank you very much in advance!,
Patricia

Comment: As discussion has started on the Liferay forums already, please see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141823/why-is-cross-posting-wrong-on-an-external-site and provide the references

Answer (score 2):

Instead of adding the JDBC driver to `lib/ext`, try to embed it into your module. You can either add something like `-includeresource: lib/ojdbc7.jar=ojdbc7-[0-9]*.jar;lib:=true` to the module's `bnd.bnd` file, or follow [these instructions](https://dev.liferay.com/develop/tutorials/-/knowledge_base/7-0/adding-third-party-libraries-to-a-module).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you very much for your answer!

I have tried it but it does not work. Also, I have tried to use the initial context instance to look up a JNDI resource inside of the FinderImpl but I got this error:

```
javax.naming.NoInitialContextException: Cannot instantiate class: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory [Root exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.naming.java.javaURLContextFactory cannot be found
```

So, I changed the classloader and it worked. The code is:

```
ClassLoader origLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(PortalClassLoaderUtil.getClassLoader());
InitialContext ctx = new InitialContext();
DataSource datasource = (DataSource) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jdbc/test1");
Connection connection = datasource.getConnection();
Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(origLoader);
```

I do not like this code very much, so finally, I have created a service builder with a external database (https://web.liferay.com/es/web/user.26526/blog/-/blogs/liferay-7-service-builder-and-external-databases).

Thanks!